# ArcScene - Spatial reference

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I am having trouble merging different layers in ArcScene. As there is no such thing as the "Georeferencing" used in ArcMap, I am not able to view two different Layers in one document.

Is there anyway to overlay two layers and show them in the same document? Or maybe any tool to spatial reference layers in a different kind of raster?

Comment: Have you tried georeferencing the datasets in ArcMap, then adding them to ArcScene?

Answer (score 0):

Are the layers on the same projection and of the same location? If they are you can go to properties and select the 'base heights' offset function to move them closer together (assuming this is a vertical difference issue?)

You can also use the same to drape one layer over the other if this is what you need?

TBH - its hard really knowing what you want as you haven't described the problem with much detail. Hope this solution helps.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Im gonna try your solution asap. But let me try to rephrase it: right now i have two layers for the excate same area. One is the "Basemap" with Bulings and their heights, the other are climate data (temperatures) in an 248x248 raster and a height of 20 Meters. But im not able to combine both, as ArcScene has no option to Georeference.

Comment: Do the files have coordinate systems set in their properties? Try using ArcCatalog to investigate their properties and if they are missing a coord system, apply a coord system....... If they are not georeferenced at all, you will need to do this in ArcMap first before applying them to a scene in ArcScene.